# Returning a Dataset with calculated fields from a Delphi REST server

Tags: rest, delphi, firedac

I have a Delphi REST server with a method that returns a dataset, the implementation looks roughly like

```
function TServerMethods1.GetData: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  //some code omitted that builds the TFDQuery
  Result := TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, MyFDQuery);
end;
```

The dataset has a large number of calculated fields, but these are ignored and only the internal data of the query is returned - any fields defined in the Field Editor (in the IDE) are ignored - including calculated fields.  Is there any way I can include the calculated fields in the result?

I've tried returning a FDMemTable and using CloneCursor or assigning the Data property, but this has the same problem.  I'm using Delphi 10.1.

Comment: I googled this for you and I found someone who said "setting the FetchOptions.Mode to fmAll on the server TFDQuery solves all the problems I reported in my post." Your milage may vary.

Comment: @nolaspeaker fmAll will return all the records, I'm after returning all the fields (particularly the calculated fields)